# OS.File check last modified date before OS.read

Tags: javascript, file-io, firefox-addon

I use `OS.File.read` to read a files contents. On focus of Window I do `OS.File.stat` and check it's last modified date. I then record this date. On next focus of window I `OS.File.stat` the file again, and if the modified date is new, then I will do a `OS.File.read` on it.

I was wondering is there a more efficient way? Like for example: I start the `OS.File.read`, and it by default gets the file header which should include date last modified, I check that as its reading and if its not a new date than I just cancel the read. This would be more efficient from a coding perspective, but from a performance perspective maybe not so much?

Comment: Thats the most efficient way i think. 1) stat 2) check date 3) read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer: Depends?!

What is more efficient would depend on the file itself and the usage pattern and the system workload.

Normally, `OS.File.stat` and then a selectively read is likely to be more efficient, because the file I/O is the likely bottleneck and you'd just avoid some I/O (most of the time).

For small files that you read often but only write occasionally, it might be more effective to just read the file. The file meta-data and data are likely in the OS disk cache so that the file I/O becomes very fast, and the actual inter-thread messaging overhead and js-ctypes overhead of `OS.File` become the bottlenecks. This is a very particular case, however.

Also, if the file changes extremely often, so that almost every `OS.stat` + check would result in having to read the file again, it might be also more efficient to just read the file. But in that case I would seriously ponder if the choice to use file was the right way to go, or if another mode of communication wouldn't be better (such as sockets).

### Conclusion

So, I'd go with `.stat`/check/`.read`, because making assumptions on the disk cache and system work load might be bad.

### Can disk I/O be avoided?

However, I'd avoid polling the file in the first place, if possible. If it is a file specific to your add-on that you do not expect other processes to write to, then read it once and after that keep the data in memory in a shared place, such as a [JS Code Module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using) or the `main.js` of SDK add-ons or `bootstrap.js` of bootstrapped add-ons. Upon writes, update the cached data as well.

If you're concerned that some other process might write your file in the mean time, then just open your file with an exclusive lock, and do not close it again while your add-on is running.

```
let options = {
  winShare: 0 // Exclusive lock on Windows
};
if (OS.Constants.libc.O_EXLOCK) {
  // Exclusive lock on *nix
  options.unixFlags = OS.Constants.libc.O_EXLOCK;
}
let file = yield OS.File.open(..., options);
```

If you expect other programs to write to the file and are fine with that, or if you use that file for a way of inter-process-communication in the first place, then you cannot avoid re-reading the file, of course.

Comment: dude u got a skill u shud be in politics. I couldn't say let alone figure out how to say more than 1 sentence..

Comment: question: If author does lock, how to unlock when addon done? Because addons likely run till shutdown of browser.

Comment: If it's a restartless add-on, you'd just explicitly close the `OS.File` handle, because the add-on might be disabled long before the browser exits. If it's a "restart" add-on, you don't really have to care. The handle will be closed once the Firefox process goes down anyway, releasing the lock (although, I'd close the file explicitly, anyway, because it's always a good idea to clean up after yourself).

Comment: Ah I see so like in the example above we'll do `file.close()`