# Sockets to read/watch file?

Tags: sockets, file-io, firefox-addon

This was prompted by this question: [OS.File check last modified date before OS.read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462115/os-file-check-last-modified-date-before-os-read)

I read that it might be wiser to use sockets to read files?

In my addon, every time the user clicks the PanelUI-popup button at top right, the new one in Australis, my add-on does a `OS.File.read` on the `profiles.ini` file to look for any changes. I do not even do `OS.File.stat` like in topic I linked above. And there is absolutely no performance issues from what I'm seeing. I have a computer from 2k4, Pentium 4, I notice any performance issues visually.

But I was waiting for a file watcher service, which is in the works right now at bugzilla. But I thought what is sockets? I searched SO but it didn't yield anything I understood they all seem to open to internet not to local file. (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[firefox-addon]+sockets)

Can sockets be used to watch a file for changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that it might be wiser to use sockets to read files?

No, I wrote that it might be wiser to use *something like* sockets for [inter-process-communication (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) **instead of** files, to avoid disk I/O and polling in the first place. (I mentioned sockets for IPC in particular, because Firefox comes with a reasonably easy-to-use, cross-platform sockets API accessible from Javascript; still: nothing to do with files).

Since you're after the contents of a particular file (`profiles.ini`) and not after IPC, you'll have to actually read that file.

Comment: Oh ok thx. I still dont understand application of sockets could you explain plz

Comment: I already linked the IPC article on wikipedia, which also links to their Sockets article(s). If you're interested in say Internet sockets (TCP, UDP, ...), then [Bej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) is probably one of the best resources online, but it is using C. There sure are guides for other languages as well.